# nmap command - suspicious behavior

Tags: command-line, 16.10, ubuntu-gnome, nmap

I'm learning Linux on Cisco, and they display a certain message about the `nmap` command :

> CAUTION: To avoid suspicion of using the tool to find a way to attack
>   the systems on your network, it is recommended that you obtain
>   authorization before using the nmap command.

Could anyone tell me why is it dangerous? Could we use `nmap` to hack a system?

Comment: do a `man nmap` and see the result I think you will understand better.

Comment: `I'm learning Linux on Cisco`. Ok. Why are you asking a question on Ubuntu site ?

Comment: @ Because I'm using Ubuntu

Comment: Helpful reading: https://nmap.org/book/legal-issues.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not by itself, but `nmap` provides useful information about target systems and networks that can be the starting point to actually hacking them. Therefore, people don't take kindly to being scanned.

If you're doing penetration testing, remember: **Always** ask for permission first. Gratuitous penetration testing could see you sued.

See also:

- [How should I tell an organisation that they are vulnerable when I wasn't given permission to check?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/17001/54387)
- [Penetration testing against an ignorant target - Is it legal?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/29517/54387)

Answer (score 5):

From `man nmap` its obvious what this tool can do. it describes it in this way:

```
is an open source tool for network exploration and security auditing
```

The tool will reveal very important information about any *network* such as:

- hosts on a network
- what services they are offering
- what operating systems they are running
- what type of packet filters/firewalls are in use
- it also list ports available in a table

The abilities of this tool makes it a useful starting point for *would be hackers*. So hence the caution given on its use. Like @muru said never use without due **authorization** from the network owner.

Yes useful for checking *network faults* but also *useful for devious minds*.

Take some time to look at the *man pages*.

Comment: What? How could we know which operating systems do they use?

Comment: please do `man nmap`. Look at the description of _nmap_ there, thats one of the many information _nmap_ gathers as it _scans_ any network.

Comment: look at the __options section__ in the _man nmap_ .